# How to relabel bars in seaborn plot?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'd like to relabel the bars in my plot. Currently, my bars are grouped and named as "A", "B", and "C" in this toy example.

How can I relabel A, B, and C to other names, e.g., "first", "second", and "third"?

Current plot and code below:
[image]

```
sns.catplot(data = data, 
            x = x,
            y = y,
            hue='condition',
            kind='bar', 
            order=['A', 'B', 'C'],
            palette=sns.color_palette(['#FF5720', '#18C288']))
```

Thanks so much for your advice in advance!

Comment: Why couldn't you just rename the data labels?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian s — while this is a toy example, my data labels are consistent across multiple data sheets that I use in R and with other collaborators. I only need to change this one plot but would prefer to do it in seaborn, rather than exporting it out to e.g., photoshop to change. (Unless I'm not fully understanding how to change data labels?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `xticklabels` inside `g.set()`. Example taken from here: [catplot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html).

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Load the example Titanic dataset
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Draw a nested barplot to show survival for class and sex
g = sns.catplot(
        x="class", 
        y="survived", 
        hue="sex", 
        data=titanic,
        height=6, 
        kind="bar", 
        palette=sns.color_palette(['#FF5720', '#18C288'])
                )

g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("survival probability")
g.set(xticklabels=["first", "second", "third"])
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I would rename the labels on the fly:

```py
fg = (
  df.replace(columns={x: {'A': 'First', 'B': 'Second', 'C': 'Third'}})
    .pipe(
      (sns.catplot, 'data'),
      x = x,
      y = y,
      hue='condition',
      kind='bar', 
      order=['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
      palette=sns.color_palette(['#FF5720', '#18C288'])
    )
)
```

This way, the axes labels won't get broken if the more categories end up in the dataframe